# Assign category to new post via URL

Tags: posts, categories, urls, parameter

There are two post categories in my WordPress site, **Blog** category and **News** category. I want to create two links in admin dashboard, each of the links will open `post-new.php` but a different category will be already selected for each of them, so that the user does not need to select them manually.

Suppose, there are two links -

1. Add Blog
2. Add News

Each link will open the `Add New Post` page, but for **Add Blog** link the category **Blog** should be selected by default, and for **Add News** link, the category **News** should be selected.

How can I achieve that? Can I set the default post category in URL?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but I wanted to achieve the same thing and I managed to do this by creating a simple plugin and thought I'd share the solution.

1. Create a new plugin file in your WordPress plugins folder, e.g., wp-content/plugins/auto-category-select/auto-category-select.php.
2. Add the following PHP code to the new plugin file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Auto Category Select
 * Description: Automatically select a category in the new post page based on a URL parameter.
 */

function auto_category_select_enqueue($hook) {
    if ('post-new.php' != $hook) {
        // Only applies to post creation page
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script('auto_category_select_script', plugins_url('auto-category-select.js', __FILE__));
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'auto_category_select_enqueue');
```

This code creates a new WordPress plugin that enqueues a JavaScript file named auto-category-select.js when the new post page is loaded.

3. Create a new JavaScript file named auto-category-select.js in the same folder as the plugin file.
4. Add the following JavaScript code to the new JavaScript file:

```
function checkCategoryCheckbox() {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const category = urlParams.get('category');
    console.log('Category from URL: ' + category);

    if (category) {
        const labels = document.querySelectorAll('.editor-post-taxonomies__hierarchical-terms-choice');
        
        if (labels.length > 0) {
            labels.forEach(function(label) {
                console.log('Label text: ' + label.textContent.trim());
                if (label.textContent.trim() === category) {
                    const checkbox = label.querySelector('input');
                    // Create a new click event
                    var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
                        'bubbles': true,
                        'cancelable': true,
                    });
                    // Dispatch the click event on the checkbox
                    checkbox.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
                    console.log('Checkbox should be checked now');
                }
            });
            // If we've found the labels, we can stop checking
            clearInterval(checkInterval);
        }
    }
}

// Start checking for the checkboxes every 500 milliseconds
var checkInterval = setInterval(checkCategoryCheckbox, 500);
```

You can then add this snippet of code to your functions.php file or by using something like the Code Snippets plugin:

```
function add_custom_links_to_admin_sidebar() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Add Blog',               // Page title
        'Add Blog',               // Menu title
        'publish_posts',          // Capability
        'post-new.php?category=Blog', // Menu slug
        '',                       // Function
        'dashicons-welcome-write-blog', // Icon URL
        6                         // Position
    );

    add_menu_page(
        'Add News', 
        'Add News', 
        'publish_posts', 
        'post-new.php?category=News', 
        '', 
        'dashicons-welcome-write-blog', 
        7
    );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_links_to_admin_sidebar');
```

Hope that helps someone out!